# how to use weak_ptr as a parameter?

Tags: c++, observable, smart-pointers

```
class Observable
{
public:
    void register(weak_ptr<Observer> x);
    void unregister(weak_ptr<Observer> x);
    void notify()
    {
        lock_guard lg(mutex_);
        for (auto it = observers_.begin(); it != observers_.end(); )
        {
            shared_ptr<Observer> pObserver(it->lock());
            if (pObserver)
            {
                pObserver->update();
                ++it;
            }
            else
            {
                it = observers_.erase(it);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    list<weak_ptr<Observer> > observers_;
    mutable mutex mutex_;
};

class Observer
{
public:
    void update();
    void oberver(weak_ptr<Observable> x)
    {
        shared_ptr<Observable> pObservable(x.lock());
        if (pObservable)
        {
            subject_ = pObservable;
        }
    }
    ~Observer()
    {
        shared_ptr<Observable> pObservable(subject_.lock());
        if (pObservable)
        {
                        //how to trans 'this' pointer to unregister?
            pObservable->unregister(...);
        }
    }
private:
    weak_ptr<Observable> subject_;
};
```

look, Observer's destructor must call unregister to remove from Observable, but how can i trans 'this' pointer as a parameter whose type is weak_ptr.

i know we only can use shared_ptr to construct a weak_ptr, but i worry about that: if i use share_ptr pObserver(this), how do i know  'this' object is in stack or heap???

Comment: If `Observer` is on the stack, then how did `Observable` manage to obtain a `weak_ptr` to it?

Comment: See also: [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)